Как сделать генератор случайных чисел в C++
Я читал одну книгу по C++ и дошел до темы с генератором случайных чисел Но не совсем понимаю как он работает. В книге сказано что компьютер генерирует псевдослучайные числа т.е. числа не являющиеся абсолютно случайными, и как будто есть решение. Насколько я понял 9 строка делает посев генератора случайных чисел и привязывается ко времени в системе. В книге оно выглядит вот так:

Но генерируются очень близкие по значению числа:

Мне хотелось бы написать абсолютный генератор случайных чисел без привязки к времени. Пробовал убрать 9 строку но программа всегда выводит 41.

Без привязки ко времени rand() всегда "засевается" одним и тем же значением... Что, кстати, удобно при отладке :)  Но вообще не надо работать с устаревшим подходом. См. 

@Harry вроде же тут есть привязка ко времени?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

@andreymal Цитирую вопрос: "Мне хотелось бы написать абсолютный генератор случайных чисел без привязки к времени. Пробовал убрать 9 строку но программа всегда выводит 41." Цитирую ответ "Без привязки ко времени rand() всегда "засевается" одним и тем же значением... Что, кстати, удобно при отладке :) Но вообще не надо работать с устаревшим подходом. См. " Что не так? Поясняю, почему всегда одно и то же значение при удалении srand, и даю советы обратить внимание на <random>, где эта проблема уже решена...

@Harry не так то, что в изначальной редакции вопроса этого предложения не было и я его не увидел ¯\(ツ)/¯


Мне хотелось бы написать абсолютный генератор случайных чисел без привязки к времени.

Абсолютных ГСЧ не бывает, к примеру, смотрите обсуждение у Кнута, Искусство программирования, т2.
Без привязки ко времени, то как минимум, при инициализации:

Использовать инструкцию процессора RDRAND, под VS: _rdrand16_step() и _rdrand32_step() (правда, это зависит от платформы);
Использовать общесистемный генератор случайных чисел, под Windows: CryptGenRandom() How to get "cryptographically strong" random bytes with Windows APIs?
Использовать С++11 class std::random_device, однако, стандарт не даёт никаких гарантий, поэтому на каждой платформе с каждой новой версией придётся проверять, что требует существенной квалификации. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device


А также см. man 7 random

Во первых, приношу извинения за неправильно сформулированный вопрос, во вторых я наивно полагал что ГСЧ в С++ работает как и в Python, но кое-что не учёл и теперь сижу ломаю голову.
В Python есть функция:
num = random.randint(a, b)

принимающая на вход два значения, a и b - диапазон чисел, из которого будут отбираться числа.
В С++ это выглядит иначе. Я немного покопался, и написал это:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int a = 10;
    int b = 1;
    

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        int random = rand();
        random = (random % a) + b;
        cout << random << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}

По сути это то же самое, что и randint() в Python, число b - это начало диапазона, a - это количество чисел для выборки, как в примере начало диапазона 1, количество чисел 10.

Если a, вдруг, станет степью двойки - не самый удачный код (впрочем, степень неудачности зависит от конкретного libc). Стоит рассмотреть использование стандартного класса std::uniform_int_distribution https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution

Вот мой пример исходного кода моей простой функции генерации случайных чисел:
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _a = 23456781;
int _b = 12323456781;
int _mod = 56472311456;
int _seed = 5123;

long rnd()
{
    _seed = (_a * _seed + _b) % _mod;
    _mod = _mod / 0.5;
    return _seed;
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int random = rnd();
        cout << random << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

Это генерация чисел на основе переполнения разрядной сетки.
Вы можете поиграться с коэффициентами и найти подходящее распределение, поменяв значение параметров и их модуляцию для переполнения, расширив её или протестировать пример и выбрать реализацию в примере, если это Вас устраивает.
Вот вторая функция для генерации случайного числа, сравните с её распределением:
long _x = 123; // начальные значения могут быть другими
long _y = 456;
long _z = 789;
long _w = 768;
long _seed2 = (long)_w;

long rnd2()
{
    long t = _x ^ (_x << 11);
    _x = _y;
    _y = _z;
    _z = _w;
    _w = (_w ^ (_w >> 19)) ^ (t ^ (t >> 8));
    _seed2 = (long)_w;
    return _seed2;
}

Вот пример первой последовательности rnd:
-13703724
-596357103
-235551766
-302927377
-433953744
-107717251
-1332608410
-932762053
-1565801460
-558298199

Вот rnd2:
252067
890666
1385621
868244
517290486
1913473473
613808793
1292734464
94374622
502991082


Этот пример хорошо демонстрирует типичные ошибки при написании генератора новичком. Ещё код использует неопределённое поведение. Читайте Кнута и стандарт C++.

Не ошибки, а преимущества. Неопределённое поведение введено специально для понятия псевдослучайное число.

Но в США (я погуглил) поведения алгоритма автора вопроса считается нормальным и не содержит ошибки. Мой ответ приведён, чтобы автор имел минимальный выбор в алгоритмах и умел создавать собственные либы, но вопрос простой и технически не понятно где это будет применятся. В заключение я могу посоветовать использовать автору приложения свой код в примере и смириться.

Младший бит вашего генератора не случаен: 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ...

Но не могу ответить почему, биты случайны, но не попадает в тот случай. Возможно требуется ввести отрицательные значения констант. Возможно мы в Матрице и первый бит не прыгает у инта и лонга. Возможно требется добавить ключевое слово signed у переменных, реализация по умолчанию может отличаться от компилятора. Для получения результатов в примерах была использована Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-разрядная версия) - Current
Версия 17.10.3

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANDU - пока вы не доказали что ваш генератор "случаен" дверять ему нельзя. А предлагать использовать новичкам - слегка аморально.

Первый бит по не понятным причинам не переполняется.

Не аморально и использовать встроенную функцию автора вопроса. Она имеет такое же распределение. Генераторы случайных чисел встречаются в азартных играх в основном, джевелбрейках, рулетках. Но используются также для генерации ключей шифрования. На C# если интересно, почему-то цифры скачут случайней.

Вот еще пример простого генератора (из man 3 rand) POSIX.1-2001 gives the following example of an implementation of rand() and srand(), possibly useful when one needs the same sequence on two different machines.  / У них тоже младшие биты не выглядят случайными (сами там пишут).

@DmitriySidyakin, по поводу ваших неслучайных младших бит. Просто возвращайте в качестве результата 32 средних. Если нужны все 64, возьмите 32 средних 2 раза и соедините их

"Неопределённое поведение введено специально для понятия псевдослучайное число." Ух.

@avp , прошу прощения, но не надо советовать за "средних бит", надо советовать провести математический анализ и/или Кнута прочитать, а после прогнать известные легкодоступные тесты, которых в сети - море.
